# Thinking Sphinx not generating results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, thinking-sphinx

Generating  error:

> undefined method `inject' for nil:NilClass

Notwithstanding the discussion at:
https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/408#issuecomment-12593562
it appears that I do have mySQL and sphinx properly installed for my postgre-based application

> MacBook-Pro-di-jerdvo:saim jerdvo$ brew install sphinx --mysql
>   Error: sphinx-2.0.3 already installed
>  MacBook-Pro-di-jerdvo:saim
>   jerdvo$ brew install mysql
>  Error: mysql-5.5.20 already installed

gemfile includes

> gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
>   gem 'pg', '0.14.1'
>   gem 'mysql2', '0.3.12b5'
>   gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.0.3'

search parameters are being captured

> {"utf8"=>"✓", "staticpage_search"=>{"terms"=>"Messina"}}

search model is running code

```
  def search(options = {})
    extra_conditions = options.delete(:conditions) || {}
    order = options.delete(:order) || '@weight DESC'
    extra_with = options.delete(:with) || {}

    with = search_with.merge(extra_with)
    conditions = search_conditions.merge(extra_conditions)

    base_class.search sanitized_terms, :conditions => conditions, :with => with, :page => page, :per_page => per_page, :sort_mode => :extended, :order => order, :retry_stale => true, :match_mode => :extended
  end

  def sanitized_terms
    @terms ||= ""
    sanitize(@terms)
  end

  def sanitize(s)
    if s.respond_to? :gsub
      s.gsub("/", "\\/")
    else
      s
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to note:

- You need Sphinx 2.0.6 or newer for TS v3 on MacOS X (due to bugs in earlier Sphinx versions with threaded daemons on OS X only).
- You need Sphinx compiled with MySQL support. Just having both MySQL and Sphinx on your system doesn't guarantee this - the best way to check is to use MySQL as your app database (just temporarily - I prefer PostgreSQL too), check that Sphinx indexes fine with that setup, then you can be sure MySQL support was compiled. That said, when you update to 2.0.6 or newer (may need to update your brew recipes), I'll be surprised if that's not the case.

Comment: That line of thought was one of my suspicions based on other discussions.  But I'm in a bit of an uncertainty bind.  Wiki for homebrew never mentions recipe; I fear I'll blunder big time.

Comment: In addition, there may be the option of manually downloading and compiling (not sure how to marry that with brew).  Which binary then for OS X 10.6 ?  2.0.6 has no OS x library package - 7 and 8 do. Or is tarball appropriate?<br /> thanks for the promptness BTW Much appreciated.

Comment: If you're compiling yourself, get the tarball. Latest Homebrew has Sphinx 2.0.7, which should work fine: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/sphinx.rb

Comment: Now it's saying you have Sphinx installed without PostgreSQL support. How do you have PostgreSQL installed?

Comment: Following a failure I had to re-build everything.  It must be homebrew.  Besides /Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql-9.1.3.tar.bz2 exists

Comment: got an index executed via brew install sphinx --mysql --pgsql and using mysql2 gem version 0.3.11, and pg gem version 0.15.1.  However configuring mysql can't connect to either /tmp/mysql.sock or 127.0.0.1. touching /tmp/mysql.sock does scant little as restart is disallowed (chown)

Comment: You need to use mysql2 0.3.12b4 or newer - earlier versions don't support multi-query statements, which Thinking Sphinx uses when searching.

Comment: Corrected. mysql was somehow confused by homebrew toggling between 5.5.20 and 5.6.1.  Now installed, running and ts:index ran fine. So MySql support is compiled.  Will now move back to postgreSQL.

Comment: Fantastic :) Let us know how that goes.

Comment: Reached 'Huzzah' stage BTW, with some ironing out left. I Miss the town where right-hand turns are done from the far-left !

Comment: Hit an odd speedbump.  rails was complaining that mysql2 was compiled against the wrong version of db. AGAIN. having gone through the loop once and documented it above, this was a surprise.  Wondering if there is an issue there.  This led to the following thought: are there any dependency issues with different postgre versions, i.e. 9.2 on development and 9.1 in production - while maintaining same post 2.0.6 sphinx, pg 0.15.1 and mysql2 0.3.12b4 - that you are aware of?

Comment: I wouldn't think there'd be any problems with either of those setups. Love your Melbourne reference, btw :)

Comment: Moved to production server. Was impeded in creating database via FATAL role '' does not exist. Given that the other apps are using that given role, I am assuming that this newer application is looking for postgre 9.2. Correct? If so, what is best way forward? Given it is a production server, I want to tread on eggshells here...

Comment: Jerome: What are you running to get that 'role does not exist' error?

Comment: Hi Pat, bundle exec rake db:create:all  and it fails on all three databases Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"saim_production", "username"=>"[...]"}  where the username is the same in all three cases.  I'm running bundle exec because there is some underlying dependency which is quietly installing 0.9.2.2

Comment: I think on Unix systems the default PostgreSQL username is 'postgres', so perhaps your username in database.yml should be that? Also, if you're invoking rails console, `RAILS_ENV=production ./script/rails console` should ensure it uses bundled gems.

Comment: That's the way it is set up (same user for other apps; postgre has users for the entire cluster, so that seems a dead end). As I'm installing for testing, I've set-up in development mode.  Still, calling production mode returns the same role "postgres" does not exist (PG::Error).  Given I installed 9.2 on localhost, in addition to 9.1 and production server has 9.1, could the app be looking for 9.2?

Comment: I don't think it's any different in behaviour across those two versions from a Rails database.yml perspective (and perhaps not even from the perspective of the pg gem). This is an issue with Rails, right? You're not invoking Thinking Sphinx rake tasks yet...

Comment: This is now a totally different question.  I've moved it into a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961927/os-x-rails3-postgresql-cannot-create-database-not-recognizing-its-default-userna

Comment: for those interested, homebrew was in the middle.  Link to question in previous comment provides the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Sphinx is required.  However, the following also was needed to get the indexing to execute:

```
brew uninstall sphinx
gem uninstall mysql2
gem uninstall thinking-sphinx
brew upgrade sphinx
brew install sphinx --mysql --pgsql
```

then re-install mysql2 and thinking-sphinx...

Note 1:
Dependencies may be an issue. mysql2 requires 0.3.12b4 minimum AND pg needs 0.15.1

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem 'pg', '0.14.1'
```

Note 2:

```
brew update
```

can also generate errors. Materially:

> This gem was compiled for 5.5.20 but the client library is 5.6.10

5.6.10 was never asked for in an upgrade, download or whatever (the system was never touched after mysql initial installation). My conclusion : brew was confusing and installed version with a more recent formula. database.yml adjusted for mysql server was Unstartable. Testing for mysql support was unverifiable.

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew upgrade mysql
brew install mysql
mysql.server start
```

got mySQL running.  At which point, the gem was compiled for the wrong, earlier, version.

```
gem uninstall mysql2
```

I chose to delete all versions.

```
bundle install
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

to create and synch up the mysql database

```
rake ts:configure
rake ts:index
```

Both ran.